# Can my soft be noticed of a change in the Windows Certificate Store ? (.NET)

Tags: c#, .net, events, event-handling, certificate-store

As the title suggests, I want to know if there is some kind of event to catch to know when Certificate Store has changed.

The goal is to detect when a user entered a specific kind of USB smartcard / stick with a signing certificate/token in it. The certificate are registered in the Windows Cert Store, ("My", personnal certificates).

I don't like the idea of detecting USB events, because there is a variable delay between the moment when the key is plugged and the moment the certificate is actually registered (and usable).

Of course, I can always set a timer that checks the store every 10 sec or so, but I hope you'll agree that it is a not elegant solution. Of course if no other good option is available, that's what I'll end up doing I guess.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

How about a hybrid approach? Watch for USB events, then when a USB key is plugged in, start polling the store every couple of seconds until you see the new cert. Still not ideal, but much closer to it than a dumb poll every ten seconds, 24/7/365.

The trick will be knowing when the USB key is of the particular type that would end up registering a certificate. If you can know this in the USB event handler, then check for it, and if the user plugs in an ordinary flash drive, don't start polling. If you can't know this, then when you detect a new connection, you might only poll the certificate store for a minute before giving up.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

I temporarily solved it by waiting until the smart card is no longer shared with another process (the Certificate Propagation Service). Not very nice and the robustness is also questionable, but it works for now.

In C#:

```
string selector = SmartCardReader.GetDeviceSelector();
DeviceInformationCollection devices = await DeviceInformation.FindAllAsync(selector);
foreach (DeviceInformation device in devices)
{
    SmartCardReader reader = await SmartCardReader.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
    reader.CardAdded += ReaderOnCardAdded;
}

private static void ReaderOnCardAdded(SmartCardReader sender, CardAddedEventArgs args)
{
    Task t = ReaderOnCardAddedAsync(sender, args);
    t.Wait();
}

private static async Task ReaderOnCardAddedAsync(SmartCardReader sender, CardAddedEventArgs args)
{
    SmartCardProvisioning provisioning = await SmartCardProvisioning.FromSmartCardAsync(args.SmartCard);

    SmartCardStatus status;
    do
    {
        status = await provisioning.SmartCard.GetStatusAsync();
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    } while (status == SmartCardStatus.Shared);

    PrintCertificatesOrDoSomethingElseUseful();
}
```

Anyone with a better solution?